# Compare multiple values in same column

Tags: sql, oracle

```
id  vid Amount  Date
a   1   10      Today
a   1   5       Yesterday
b   2   6       Today
b   2   7       Yesterday
```

How to Get the row where amount for today is greater than amount for yesterday group by id and vid. Date column is in date time format for today's date and yesterday's

I require the first row as result

Comment: Edit your question and provide the desired output.

Comment: No, _you_ get the row!

Comment: If your database supports it, use lead or lag.

Comment: Is this a question or an instruction?

Comment: @GarethD, that's a nice comment + 1 ... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what type of data you can have there, but you can try this query. This will return all today rows for which all yesterday amounts are less. This is for `MS SQL Server`, but `ORACLE` also supports `ALL` condition, so you can just replace table variables with your table name:

```
declare @t table(id char(1), vid int, amount int, date char(10))

insert into @t values
('a', 1, 10, 'Today'),
('a', 1, 5, 'Yesterday'),
('b', 2, 6, 'Today'),
('b', 2, 7, 'Yesterday')

select * from @t t1
where t1.date = 'Today' and 
      t1.amount > ALL(select t2.amount from @t t2 
                      where t1.id = t2.id and t1.vid = t2.vid and t2.date = 'Yesterday')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             lag(amount) over (partition by id, vid order by date) as prev_amount
      from t
     ) t
where amount > prev_amount;
```